# Whatsapp is not installing on Lumia 535

Tags: whatsapp, store, nokia-lumia-535

I am using Lumia 535 OS Windows 8.1. Facing problem when installing the Whatsapp. It is showing "Attention required, tap here" as I tap there, showing as "we are having trouble connecting to the Store at the moment. Try again in a little while. If I click on "Try again" same thing comes again.

I am not using a SD Card. Whatsapp application is in Windows phone only.

Answer (score 1):

Check your internet connection first I think. I face this problem when my wifi connection disconnects or speed becomes slow. 
And also do check in your *settings* what type of file you have selected to download when on **Wifi** and when on **Cellular Network.**

Answer (score 0):

Had same issue with a Game, and I never managed to re-install it. Finally I did a complete back up and hard reset my Phone. That was the only solution.

Waiting for an easier workaround.